# Plotting Extended Zone Scheme:

Tags: plotting

How could I present an extended zone scheme for a delta-function Kronig-Penney model? That is, how can I display only the lowest contour in the region [0, π], the second-lowest contour in the region [π, 2π], etc.? The dispersion relation is $\cos(k) = 5\rm{sinc}(5.12\sqrt{E}) + \cos(5.12\sqrt{E})$. My code for the reduced zone scheme (where all contours are displayed in the region [0, π]) is:

```
ContourPlot[
  Cos[k] == Cos[5.12 Sqrt[e]] + 5*Sinc[5.12 Sqrt[e]], {k, 0, π}, {e, 0.1, 1.52},
  FrameLabel -> {"k[\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(nm\), \(-1\)]\)]", "Energy[eV]"}, 
  PlotLabel -> Cos[k] == Cos[5.12 Sqrt[e]] + 5*Sinc[5.12 Sqrt[e]]]
```

which works fine, but I cannot see how to generalize this to the extended zone scheme.

Comment: see, this is a site for questions on mathematica. you pose a question which is impossible to understand except by people who know what the Kronnig-Penney model, the extended zone scheme, Bloch theorem etc are.  Please reformulate it

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is a bit of a hack, but it seems to work. We want to detect when the winding numbers in the periodic functions are equal. Use `Floor` and add the result to the contour equation as an imaginary component. The contour will not be displayed unless both the real and imaginary parts are equal.

```
ContourPlot[
 Cos[k] + I Floor[k/\[Pi]] == 
  Cos[5.12 Sqrt[e]] + 5 Sinc[5.12 Sqrt[e]] + 
   I Floor[5.12 Sqrt[e]/\[Pi]], {k, 0, 3 \[Pi]}, {e, 0, 3.5}, 
 GridLines -> {({#1 \[Pi], Dashed} &) /@ Range[3], None}, 
 FrameLabel -> {SequenceForm[k, 
    " [\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(nm\), \(-1\)]\)]"], "Energy [eV]"}, 
 PlotLabel -> Cos[k] == Cos[5.12 Sqrt[e]] + 5 Sinc[5.12 Sqrt[e]]]
```

[image: Extended zone plot]

Comment: This is fantastic. Thanks!

Comment: In case you want to help to answer the same question in another programming language, check https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/30204/plot-a-multi-variable-equation-in-discontinuous-regions?noredirect=1#comment55465_30204