# Plotting Extended Zone Scheme: plot -3pi to 3pi

Tags: plotting

[Plotting Extended Zone Scheme:](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/20624/plotting-extended-zone-scheme)

[image: i want to know plot this -3pi to 3pi how can i]`ContourPlot[
  Cos[k] == Cos[5.12 Sqrt[e]] + 5*Sinc[5.12 Sqrt[e]], {k, 0, π}, {e, 0.1, 1.52},
  FrameLabel -> {"k[\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(nm\), \(-1\)]\)]", "Energy[eV]"}, 
  PlotLabel -> Cos[k] == Cos[5.12 Sqrt[e]] + 5*Sinc[5.12 Sqrt[e]]]`

i want to know plot this -3pi to 3pi how can i

Comment: The code you've posted does not correspond to the image. Could you tell us which parameter range do you want to alter and where are you stuck?

Comment: i want plot k range [-3pi to 3pi] vs e

Comment: who anser k range [0 to 3pi] as ContourPlot[
 Cos[k] + I Floor[k/\[Pi]] == 
  Cos[5.12 Sqrt[e]] + 5 Sinc[5.12 Sqrt[e]] + 
   I Floor[5.12 Sqrt[e]/\[Pi]], {k, 0, 3 \[Pi]}, {e, 0, 3.5}, 
 GridLines -> {({#1 \[Pi], Dashed} &) /@ Range[3], None}, 
 FrameLabel -> {SequenceForm[k, 
    " [\!\(\*SuperscriptBox[\(nm\), \(-1\)]\)]"], "Energy [eV]"}, 
 PlotLabel -> Cos[k] == Cos[5.12 Sqrt[e]] + 5 Sinc[5.12 Sqrt[e]]]

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can use [`RegionFunction`](http://reference.wolfram.com/language/ref/RegionFunction):

```
ContourPlot[
    Cos[k] == Cos[5.12 Sqrt[e]] + 5 Sinc[5.12 Sqrt[e]],
    {k,0,3 Pi}, {e,0.1,3.5},
    RegionFunction -> (
        (IntervalMemberQ[Interval[Pi^2 (Quotient[#,Pi]+{0,1})^2/5.12^2], #2])&
    )
]
```

[image]